# 'return' outside function SyntaxError using visual studio

Tags: python-3.x, return

Here is the lines of code i am getting that error from:

```
cornersOpen = []              
for i in possibleMoves:
    if i in [1, 3, 7, 9]:
       cornersopen.append(i)

if len(cornersOpen) > 0:
   move = selectRandom (cornersOpen)
   return move

if 5 in possibleMoves:
    move = 5
    return move

edgesOpen = []
for i in possibleMoves:
    if i in [2, 4, 6, 8]:
       edgesOpen.append(i)

if len(edgesOpen) > 0:
   move = selectRandom (edgesOpen)

return move
```

I am using visual Studio 2015 and every return word has a red line underneath, not too sure where is the indentation should be.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation looks fine (in terms of what we can see, anyway).

However, unless that code is actually *within* a function, `return` is indeed invalid. You can only return from a function, such as with:

```
def GiveMe42():
    return 42
```

Comment: Greatly appreciate you getting back to me.  But as you can tell, I am knew to coding, and i was following a video, followed the same exact steps, however, my code does not run, but from the video everything looks the same, as he did it.

Not too sure what else i can do.

Can i share the video link here?

Comment: @OceansBlue: sure, post the link in a comment and let us know roughly where it is (in terms of, for example, 3m56s in). Then we can let you know where the issue is.

Comment: My apology for the late reply.

Here is the link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAaJZLqryTI

@ min 12:40

Comment: @Oceans, that code should be within a function as per the video. We still can't tell if your code is okay since you haven't posted the full function. You'll need to do that for complete help but I'm almost certain your code simply doesn't match the video. Most likely you've finished the function by outdenting to column 1 somewhere.